# How to run su from PHP launched on Apache?

Tags: php, terminal, su

I tried to run su command with PHP shell_exec function. At first I tried:

```
<?php
echo(shell_exec('echo \'password\' | su user -c \'whoami\' 2>&1;'));
?>
```

and I got:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

Then I've read about spawning terminal with python's pty and put it into the shell code:

```
<?php
echo(shell_exec('echo "if [ -t 1 ] ; then echo "terminal found"; fi; echo \'password\' | su user -c \'whoami\';  exit" | python -c \'import pty; pty.spawn("/bin/bash")\' 2>&1;'));
?>
```

and here's the output:

```
if [ -t 1 ] ; then echo terminal found; fi; echo 'password' | su user -c 'whoami';  exit
www-data@server:/some/directory$ if [ -t 1 ] ; then echo terminal found; fi; echo 'password' | su user -c 'whoami';  exit
terminal found
su: must be run from a terminal
exit
```

Any idea why pty isn't working or what other tool should I use to spawn a terminal?
PHP runs behind Apache on Debian.

EDIT: I am searching for a workaround that doesn't require physical access to server or connecting via SSH. Suppose that I want to use su to start sshd and only working servers are FTP and Apache.

Comment: You should take a look at sudo/

Comment: sudo would be nice if www-data were in sudoers file. Unfortunately it isn't and I cannot change sudoers without root access or SSH connection.

Comment: What reason do you have to need to use the account of another user?

Comment: For example, restarting SSH server. First, I have to su on user that is in sudoers, then sudo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't appear to have sufficient access to the system to do it correctly.

Comment: Well, I've managed to run su with help of netcat and python's pty - look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend have shown me how to get tty and then su.

```
<?php
shell_exec('nc -l -p 1234 -c /bin/sh');
?>
```

Then you have to telnet on port 1234 and enter those commands:

```
python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/bin/sh")'
tty
```

and it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

**The answer (not a solution) is simply *you can't*.**

Good admin will prevent it always. It's a very bad idea and you know you should avoid it and use some better solution.

E.g. set just a flag via php (FTP or any other method)

I.e. schedule some actions (e,g. restart SSH server) when a specific flag is set via php (eg. file is present, json response or db value).

The trigger can by anything from PHP,
but the key is that the action should be pre-defined and with solid, expected result, with a fallback when the php part fails (eg. when someone manages to trigger the php part without your permission).

Another solution might be to write bash scripts performing required actions, set up password-less access to those scripts (in `sudoers` file) and run them via php.

Comment: I can - please look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very bad idea to run anything su related via PHP on a web server. It opens up too many possibilities for server compromise.

If some particular executable needs to be run as root, you can use `sudo` mechanism to do that. Unfortunately configuring `sudo` takes quite much effort.

Comment: I know it's a bad idea, but sometimes it's necessary, like for restarting SSH. Suppose I accidentaly stopped SSH server and have only FTP - what should I do (except physical access to server, of course)?

Comment: @Patryk Hes In that case configure `sudo` something like this `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/ssh *` and then call `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start|stop|restart` within your `php` code.

Comment: Well, if you want to prevent "stop SSH server accidentally" from happening, then having a script to run the command is one way. Another way would be to have a cron job that checks for existence of some file, and if the file exists, SSH is restarted and file is deleted. FTP isn't secure either btw.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen using cron is a good idea. Still it can't help me in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If must to use `su` from your php program then the correct way is to use it through `expect`. You can use a small script:

```
#!/use/bin/expect -f

spawn "su some_user -c cmd.sh"
expect {
    ssword: { send "myStrongPass\r" }
}
interact
```

But, you should be aware that this creates a security risk - you are storing a clear text password of a user in a file readable by a webserver. And that user has access to `sudo`.. You should carefully think about it.

Comment: Seems plausible, but you have to have installed expect first. Maybe it would help someone with expect installed and no netcat.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `su` directly, run it via `sudo` made sure, you've given Apache's user permission to do that w/o password, so it'd be as simple as: `sudo su …`. You can also (and you'd better) limit what commands are to be run using `sudo` pattern matching and of course you can use `sudo` itself w/o making it invoke `su`.

Comment: Mind the situation - I couldn't use sudo, because I couldn't edit sudoers file. That would require physical access or SSH connection.